# How do I read in a php array, in Objective-C?

Tags: php, objective-c, associative-array

In php I have:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
// if successful query, return the records
if ($result)
{
    // if not empty result, return array of records
    if (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $records = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $records[] = $row;
        }
        return $records;
    }
     }
```

In Objective-C - After the POST I have the following code...

```
NSURLResponse *newStr = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&newStr error:nil];
```

returnData is equal to the literal "Array", not the contents of $records[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should serialise the data into a XML type `plist` format if you can, then it can be natively interpreted by Cocoa classes like NSArray and NSDictionary. NSPropertyListSerializer is capable of producing mutable or immutable arrays and dictionaries from a file or from an NSData object containing serialized data in plist format.

NSDictionary can also read files in this format:

```
"key" = "value";
"key2" = "value2";
```

Likewise, NSArray can read files in this format:

```
(
     "value1",
     "value2",
     "value3",
     "30",
     "value5"
);
```

In fact, I think if the strings don't contain spaces, the quotes are optional (but I guess they would force string types).

Check out [this URL](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html) for more information about oldschool ASCII property lists. They are read-only, but then again they are easy enough to generate manually or systematically.

Comment: All good responses. Dreamlax, Good Idea. That makes a lot more sense to me now, especially since I'm not familiar with JSON. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to format your array in some format that you can read in Objective-C. I recommend using [JSON](http://json.org).

If you have PHP 5.2, you can use [the built in functions](https://www.php.net/json) to encode your data. For example:

```
echo json_encode($records);
```

On the Objective-C side, you can use [TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON) to decode/encode JSON.

Comment: I'm stuck with php version 4.4.9 unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

On the PHP side you need to serialize the array to a format like JSON or XML rather than just `print`ing it. On the iPhone side would then deserialize the `NSData` object using the appropriate library

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm using php version 4.4.9, which doesn't support JSON, so I used XML instead. Thanks for the Answer.